# How can we obtain the sublocality for the United States? I've tried, but it returns null for the USA, while I can get the sublocality for India

Tags: android, kotlin

```
val geocoder = Geocoder(this@MapFragment.requireContext(), Locale.US)

            val addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1)

            if (addresses!!.size > 0) {

                val address = addresses[0]

                Log.d("sdfsdfsdfdfds", "${address.subLocality}")

}
```

We tried to change Locale.getDefault() but still not getting sublocality for USA.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We want to get subLocality of any US Lat long using geocoder or else